# Are there any proper FREE virusscanners that can be deployed and managed from Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, anti-virus

The question pretty much says it all.

I have been looking for free solutions and have not found any so far, which leads me to think that there simply aren't any.

**Requirements:**

- Deployable from a Windows 2008 Server
- Remote management from the server

If I am overlooking something, I'd love to hear. If not, too bad, but at least I'll know I'll have to look for paid solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently been looking for this as well. I have found that the free antivirus software vendors that offer remote management start charging when you need this functionality. It makes sense since all of the free antivirus offerings that I have seen are for personal use only. And once you need more advanced functionality you will have to pay for it.

So I think you should start looking for which paid solution fits your needs.